# how to looping particular row through dataset and set to treeview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to loop through each data row and check the value of pid until it get 0 or null or empty value...below is my code

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pIDstr))
{
    int patientID = Convert.ToInt32(pID);

    //string connection = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ConnectionString;
    string sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM [MyDatabase].[dbo].[PatExam] where PId = '" + patientID + "'";
    string connection = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ConnectionString;
    using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection))
    {
        //SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(con);
        DataSet ds;
        ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter cmpatientexam;
        conn.Open();

        cmpatientexam = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlquery, conn);
        cmpatientexam.Fill(ds, "PatientExam");

        foreach (DataRow patrow in ds.Tables["PatientExam"].Rows)
        {

                TreeNode tvpatexam = new TreeNode();
                tvpatexam.Text = patrow["PId"].ToString();
                TreeView1.Nodes.Add(tvpatexam);

                for //loop for checking all the patrow["PId"] value
                {
                    TreeNode childtvpatexam = new TreeNode();
                    childtvpatexam.Text = patrow["Exam"].ToString();
                    tvpatexam.ChildNodes.Add(childtvpatexam);
                }
            //TreeView1.Nodes.Add(tvpatexam);
        }


        ds.Dispose();
        cmpatientexam.Dispose();
        conn.Close();
        conn.Dispose();
    }
}
```

How these is possible can anybody send the code...thanks a lot

My database table PatExam contains the following value

```
PId     Exam
1004    firstexam
1004    secondexam
1004    thridexam
1004    fourthexam
```

so I want 1004 as my parent node and all exam value of 1004 as child node in tree view....

How can it be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a child node for each parent node, try the following

```
TreeNode pidNode = new TreeNode();
pidNode.Text = PIDstr;

foreach (DataRow patrow in ds.Tables["PatientExam"].Rows)
{
    TreeNode examType = new TreeNode();
    examType.Text = patrow["Exam"].ToString();
    pidNode.Nodes.Add(examType);
}

TreeView1.Nodes.add(pidNode);
```

There is no need to check for `Null` or `0` values - Not sure what you were asking.

**Update**

If the node is repeatedly being added; it means that the action use to generate the node list is repeat.  You can either use `TreeView1.Nodes.Clear()` to remove all the nodes or you can check if the specific node exists.

To remove all nodes try something like

```
TreeView1.Nodes.Clear();
```

To remove the specific node and refresh it's contents try something like before repopulating the node.

```
TreeNode node = TreeView1.Nodes.FirstOrDefault(p=>p.Text == PIDstr);
TreeView1.Nodes.Remove(node);
```

Comment: i try as follows.....if (patrow["PId"] == DBNull.Value || patrow["PId"].ToString() == "0") 
                                 {
                                        TreeNode childtvpatexam = new TreeNode();
                                        childtvpatexam.Text = patrow["Exam"].ToString();
                                        tvpatexam.ChildNodes.Add(childtvpatexam);
                                 }
                                 break;......but it does not go inside the if condition....what wrong?

Comment: @Pratik you have the `break` outside the `{ }` block. A loop ends when it check statement is true or when it first encounters a `break` statement.

Comment: i have put inside the { } block as you see  if (patrow["PId"] == DBNull.Value || patrow["PId"].ToString() == "0") 
                                 {
                                        TreeNode childtvpatexam = new TreeNode();
                                        childtvpatexam.Text = patrow["Exam"].ToString();
                                        tvpatexam.ChildNodes.Add(childtvpatexam);
                                        break;
                                 } but the point it doesn't go inside the if condition....y?

Comment: @Pratik Because the conditions for the if statement are not met. You have no element that is `DBNull` or equal to `0`. Check your data.

Comment: there is data for patrow["PId"] i can see in the root node of tree view as patientid but i want childnode of that patientid

Comment: @Pratik You have lost me.  You are asking to identify where `PId` is null, yet this comment is different. Review your original question. Include a sample of your data and show where you are having trouble.

Comment: my database table name is PatExam which contains two columns one PId and another columnn is Exam, the PId == 1004 columnn contain 4 times in the table with different examination like firstexam, secondexam, thirdexam and fourexam....i am getting parent root node in treeview as 1004 but not any childnode...like firstexam, secondexam, thirdexam and fourexam

Comment: @Pratik Like I said above; You have lost me. I cannot follow what you are trying to achieve.  It might be better if you edit your question with additional information.  The comments section here does not provide enough room.

Comment: I have edited the question...if you still have any trouble in understanding then please let me know?

Comment: but now the problem is when i click on button twice then treeview is generating same pid and examination again....do u have any idea why these is happening?

Comment: i have put these entire code inside the gridview row command like protected void gvDoctorList_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        { }

Comment: i think i need to clear the treeview when the click event is finish what do you think?

Comment: yes node is repeatedly adding by clicking on the select button in gridview i try to put the TreeView1.Nodes.Clear(); at the end of the event then treeview is alway clear...where should i put now?